# What is wrong with the resized memoir page?

Tags: memoir, wallpaper, resize

I want to make a cover page (for an eBook-like format) with a background image, the size (and aspect ratio) of which is not known in advance. I would like to cover the page with the image (the best way, i.e either the max. width or max. height, but no white stripes), then put some texts in boxes on top of it. Below you find an MWE and its output.

1. The wallpaper [Golden ratio] has some margin (both vertical and horizontal)
2. The box (Red text) of `width=\paperwidth` at north, has a right side margin and a top margin
3. The box [Green text] of `width=\textwidth` at south west, has no bottom margin, but has right margin
4. The box [Gray text] of `width=\paperwidth` at east, is positioned at some foreign place.
5. The box [Blue text] at west, seems to have a vertical position different from the vertical position of box [Gray text], positioned at east
6. It looks like `\paperwidth` is not the width of the paper

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setstocksize{4.8in}{3.6in}
\settrimmedsize{4.65in}{3.45in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0mm}{2mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{7mm}{1mm}{*}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{.7\baselineskip}{0\baselineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
    \CenterWallPaper{.98}{example-image-golden} 
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
\node[fill=gray,font=\LARGE\bfseries,text=black,%
minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=2em,anchor=north]%
at (current page.east){Gray text};
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
\node[fill=blue!50!white,font=\LARGE\bfseries,text=black,%
minimum width=.5\paperwidth,minimum height=2em,anchor=west]%
at (current page.west){Blue text};
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
\node[fill=green!50!black,font=\LARGE\bfseries,text=black,%
minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=2em,anchor=south west]%
at (current page.south west){Green text};
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
\node[fill=red!50!black,font=\LARGE\bfseries,text=black,%
minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=2em,anchor=north]%
at (current page.north){Red text};
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the anchor for Gray text correct? Shouldn't it be `east` rather than `north`?

Comment: The main problem is surely the difference between `\setstocksize` and `\settrimmedsize`: you are asking for a smaller trimmed size than stocksize, which is normal enough, but TikZ works (I'd guess from you image) from the stocksize, which is the 'true' size of the PDF. You should either compensate for that or set the two sizes to be equal. As for the `Green text`, you are asking for `\textwidth`, not `\paperwidth`, and you have asked for a right-hand margin of `2 mm` with `\setlrmarginsandblock{0mm}{2mm}{*}`. You need to compensate for that also, or get rid of the margin.

Comment: @jon That means, I neet two different settings for the cover page and title pages? or is there some better trick? (probably yes: if I use A4 size, no similar proble occurs)

Comment: Well, you can keep the set up now if you compensate for what TikZ is doing. The values you would need to compensate for are already known, so it wouldn't be tricky to do it. Otherwise, the package `geometry` can do `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`.

Comment: @ jon  Hm. In some other message I was counteradvised to use geometry with memoir.